# how do i add variables to url requests in javascript, more specifically, expo and react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

i am currently making this request via fetch in expo

```
const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{{{i need to enter the id here}}}/friends?access_token=${token}`);
```

I have user.id but I am not sure how to call id in the string

here is the entire function, everything works except the {id} in the string

```
login = async () => {
  const ADD_ID = '<APP ID>'
  const options = {
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_friends'],
  }
  const {type, token} = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(ADD_ID, options)
  if (type === 'success') {
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`)
    const user = (await response.json());
    const id = user.id;
    console.log(user);
    console.log(id);
    this.authenticate(token)
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{id}/friends?access_token=${token}`);
    console.log(await response.json())
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmm it throws an error {"line":1324,"column":94,"sourceURL":"....=false&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=expo/tools/hashAssetFiles"}

Comment: i needed to put the try catch inside of the "if" statement to have access to the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let define your own format String function and move your `try catch` inside if expression

```js
String.format = function() {
    // The string containing the format items (e.g. "{0}")
    // will and always has to be the first argument.
    var theString = arguments[0];
    
    // start with the second argument (i = 1)
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        // "gm" = RegEx options for Global search (more than one instance)
        // and for Multiline search
        var regEx = new RegExp("\\{" + (i - 1) + "\\}", "gm");
        theString = theString.replace(regEx, arguments[i]);
    }
    
    return theString;
}
console.log(String.format('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{0}/friends?access_token=${1}', id, token))
```

Comment: i updated the post with the code. please let me know if you can identify the issue or if the code is redundant in any way

Comment: String.format('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{0}/friends?access_token=${1}', id, token) doesn't work?

Comment: the id isn't available inside the Try Catch for some reason but the token is?

Comment: It seems you only have user.id when the response success. let's try to move try catch inside if expression

Comment: yep that was the issue. if you update the answer to reflect the code i'll mark it as the answer.